# What scope is an undeclared variable used deep in code?

Tags: perl, scope

```
# my @arr;   
for (1..100)
{
    for (1..100)
    {
        for (1..100)
        {
            push @arr, 1;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the scope of `@arr`?  Is it the same as if it was declared in the commented line at the top?

Answer (score 8):

The `@arr` is a global variable, created when it is first encountered by the parser, and then seen in the whole package.

```
use warnings;
#use strict;

for (1..3) {
    #my @arr;
    for ( qw(a b c) ) {
        push @arr, $_;
    }   
}

print "@arr\n";
```

It prints

```
a b c a b c a b c
```

This is one of the bad things about globals, that they "radiate" throughout the code.

With `use strict;` enabled we get

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @arr in string at scope.pl line 11.
Global symbol "@arr" requires explicit package name at scope.pl line 7.
Global symbol "@arr" requires explicit package name at scope.pl line 11.
Execution of scope.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Since `strict` merely enforces declarations, this meaningfully informs us that `@arr` is global (thus seen everywhere in the code).

Declaring it with `my` at the top would have the same effect in this example, but it is not the same thing as an undeclared, global variable.  A `my` variable is lexical and has scope, the nearest enclosing block (or file, here). From [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html)

> A `my` declares the listed variables to be local (lexically) to the enclosing block, file, or `eval`. If more than one variable is listed, the list must be placed in parentheses.

Also, lexicals are not in the symbol table.

So when it is declared inside the first loop (commented out line) then the following `push @arr...` refers to *that* variable, which does not exist outside of that loop's block (and so is not seen at the end). The last line then refers to another variable, a global `@arr` created right there,<sup>†</sup> which was never assigned to. We do get the warning

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @arr in string at scope.pl line 11.
Name "main::arr" used only once: possible typo at scope.pl line 11.
```

about empty `main::arr` used once, and an empty line since it is printed.

See also [Private variables via `my()` in perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29)

---

<sup>†</sup> At compile time, when it is first seen by the parser

Comment: "*created when it is first used*" - technically the parser creates it when it is first seen, not necessarily used (e.g. `if (0) { print @arr; }` would create `@main::arr` at compile time (assuming `no strict`)).

Comment: @melpomene  Good point, and I've just considered changing that (while making another small edit)!  The thing is, I've been asked questions about use of "_seen_" (referring to compilers "seeing" symbols, which I thought was absolutely clear) ... changed it now,  thank you :)